# Is there a way to catch expression change error?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting NG0100 error (Expression changed) in my console. Is there any way I can catch this error in my code and print it in the console via my code?

I tried try catch block but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
try{
//error generating code
}
catch(e){
console.log(e.message)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, catch a NG0100 won't help that much. It's not a blocking error, it's just a big warning to tell yout that your code is unsafe and some expressions change at a point of the component genereation where it shouldn't.

It is supported by Angular DoubleCheck wich is a system that check your template binded attributes to make sure your code is stable and predictable. NG0100 means your expression has changed between these two checks.
It is just a warning because this DoubleCheck only exists in devmode (aka ng serve or ng build --configuration developement).

Best you can do is find why and where this happens in your code, to avoid it.
The informations given can't let us know, but you can watch [this video](https://angular.io/errors/NG0100) from Angular official documentation that explains most common reasons of NG0100

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I've figured out why it's throwing that error but I just wanted to know whether I can still catch it or not because it doesn't look like it's possible to capture it in catch.